# How can I export the summary data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R and I would like to export this summary as a PNG file. Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

```
library(summrytools)
summary_data <- summarytools::descr(iris)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To export it as PNG, you can use:

```
library(gridExtra)
png("test.png", height = 50*nrow(summary_data), width = 200*ncol(summary_data))
grid.table(summary_data)
dev.off()
```

Result:
[image: Iris Dataset Summary as PNG]